# Marklogic how to loop each node

Tags: marklogic

I try to loop each `$node` to get element then return `string-join()` of all elements together in `local:function`.  but it is not working.

> XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) local:test-case($value) -- Invalid coercion: "EF127557 Y" as node().

I could not figure out what it means of this error code.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace techco="http://techco.com/db/record";
declare namespace meta="http://techco.com/db/record/meta";

declare function local:test-case($nodes as node()*) as node()* {
let $pl := for $node in $nodes
            let $ANumber        := $node/db:Record/meta:Metadata/meta:ANumber
            let $ActiveFlag             := $node/db:Record/meta:Metadata/meta:ActiveFlag
            let $value:=   fn:string-join(($ANumber,$ActiveFlag)," ")                                         
              return $value

return $pl
};

let $query:=cts:and-query((
                    ....
        ))

let $value := cts:search(
                   fn:doc(),
                   $query
)
  return local:test-case($value)
```

Comment: could you provide example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I can't test this because of not having example data but this should work now. The problem was your return type was set as `node()` and needed to be `xs:string*`. an ***Invalid coercion:*** error means the data type its getting is not what it is expecting.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace techco="http://techco.com/db/record";
declare namespace meta="http://techco.com/db/record/meta";

declare function local:test-case($nodes as node()*) as xs:string* {
let $pl := for $node in $nodes
            let $ANumber        := $node/db:Record/meta:Metadata/meta:ANumber
            let $ActiveFlag             := $node/db:Record/meta:Metadata/meta:ActiveFlag
            let $value:=   fn:string-join(($ANumber,$ActiveFlag)," ")                                         
              return $value

return $pl
};

let $query:=cts:and-query((
                    ....
        ))

let $value := cts:search(
                   fn:doc(),
                   $query
)
  return local:test-case($value)
```